Why do i get this ANgular Injector Error , But only in the browser console
I am trying to set up FireStore and keep getting an error in the console after the ap was compiled. The compiler is giving no errors just the browser console.
**Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Firestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.firestore-instances -> [object Object] -> FirebaseApps -> FirebaseApps]: **
here is my Component
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { collection, addDoc, collectionData, Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class PickComponent {



  constructor(private fs: Firestore) {

  }

  addData(f:any){
 const fpicks = collection(this.fs, 'users');
    addDoc(fpicks, f.value);
        console.log(f.value);
      }

  
}




is the github repo public to check? try this answer

A NullInjectorError usually means that you need to provide the Module / Store / Service or whatever. 
I assume you are using standalone components? 
Either add the Firestore to your component provider array or add it to the bootstrap.
